# Can't send authorization token to flask api with post request

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm working on an API written in python using flask but I'm having trouble sending a post request with authorization. I'm using axios to make the requests.

I tried pretty much everything I found on this link [[Solve Cross Origin Resource Sharing with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980713/solve-cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-flask)]

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST","GET"])
# @cross_origin is commented for the get request
@cross_origin(methods=["POST"], allow_headers=['Content-
def test():
    return jsonify({'success':True})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

```
// change post to get
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/test', {
  // withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
    'Authorization': 'token'
  }
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The authorization token comes up in the headers when I use get but not post

get request:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjxdD.png

post request:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu1OS.png

**EDIT (SOLVED?)**

not really a solution but I switched to fetch and that solved my issue but I couldn't figure out why it was happening in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the `*` with `http://localhost:5000/test` , you should allow access for a specific domain.

Another way is to initialize `flask-cors` with default arguments:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```