# SameSite cookie being blocked

Tags: python, cookies, cross-domain, backend, samesite

**Quick overview**:
I open my website at ***domain1***. Inside a page, I load an iframe with url ***http://domain2/...***

I keep on getting this warning on chrome and it has affected my website:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at ***http://domain2*** was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

I never had to set cookies before so I'm unaware where the cookie should be set from. I've already tried setting `proxy_cookie_path` in my ***domain2*** nginx config but it doesn't seem to work:

```
location / {
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; SameSite=None; Secure";
}
```

I also tried adding `Set-Cookie` header which also doesn't seem to work:

```
location / {
    ...
    add_header 'Set-Cookie' 'SameSite=None; Secure';
}
```

When I tried the second solution, it seems the the header was received from the response on chrome, but chrome gives the following warning:

[image]

Note that ***domain2*** is our domain as well, and it has a python backend using Flask framework. So should I add the cookies from the python code or javascript frontend?

This is getting really frustrating.

Comment: Try using `SameSite=Strict` in the response from server.

Comment: @Liju doesn't this block requests that are cross domain?

Comment: It will, If you want to use domain2 cookie in domain1, as per this [chromium blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/samesite-cookie-changes-in-february.html) you need to set the cookie as `Set-Cookie: name=value; SameSite=None; Secure;` for chrome, and in the screenshot you provided there is no cookie value pair. please check if that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Site Resource Sharing - CORS is a known issue when a request is sent through the same domain. You may try using already existing [flask cors package](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to allow the same origin requests.

In addition, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26980713/7470786) question and answer seems relevant to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I used this `proxy_cookie_flags ~ secure samesite=none;` in the blocks `server { }` and `location { }` and it worked.