# Heroku Multiple Buildpacks (Python and PHP)

Tags: python, php, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Python app on Heroku, and have a simple html page that uses it (for now a simple Hello World will do). I think I have successfully deployed the Python app, and it's functioning properly, because when I send a POST request to the url, I get the correct output:

```
import requests

resp = requests.post('https://name-classification.herokuapp.com/predict', data={'name': 'Marshall'})

print(resp.text)
```

Output:

```
{"name":"Marshall","predictoin":"English"}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But it seems that the html / PHP part is not working, since I'm seeing a 404 not found error when I visit the [webpage](https://name-classification.herokuapp.com):

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

From what I read I understand that I need to have an `index.php` file in the root directory, which refers to the `html` file, also in the main directory. So this is my project structure:

```
+root
  +app
    -__init__.py
    -main.py
    -torch_utils.py
  -.gitignore
  -composer.json
  -home.html
  -index.php
  -Procfile
  -wsgi.py
```

**home.html:**

```
Hello World!
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>
```

**composer.json:**

```
{}
```

And following [Heroku's tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) for setting multiple buildpacks for multi languages in the same project, I did the following

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/php
```

And it seems that the buildpacks were set successfully:

```
heroku buildpacks
=== name-classification Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/php
2. heroku/python
```

But after committing and pushing my changes, I still see the 404 not found error.

Do I need to do anything more to make it work?

Comment: Only one buildpack is actually used at runtime. If you have two different apps, use two different dynos.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks, that worked (I had to enable cross domain though to avoid CORS error, which I did by following these answers: [\[1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997253/900394) or [\[2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637194/900394))