# Why are cross-origin POST requests with Content-Type 'application/json' considered to be unsafe?

Tags: json, fetch, httprequest, cross-domain

According to

https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin#unsafe-requests

> Safe headers – the only allowed custom headers are:
> ...
> `Content-Type` with the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`.

If I understand the consequences correctly:

Sending a cross origin `POST` request with `Content-Type` header `appliation/json` will first trigger a **preflight** `OPTIONS` request, that needs to be handled correctly...before handling the actual `POST` request.

=> Why is `application/json` considered to be unsafe; what would be the risk of accepting the request directly?

(I already spend hours of trying to fix CORS settings and would like to understand the underlying issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST requests are considered to be [unsafe](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) because they are supposed to change things on the server.

For example: You don’t want Alice to visit Mallory's evil site and have some Ajax there make an HTTP POST request to the Intranet for the company that Alice works for and create an appointment for Mallory to come to the office and get past security. Not do you want Mallory’s site to be able to delete all the messages in your webmail. Etc.

POST requests with content-types that you can set in the `enctype` attribute aren’t preflighted … but you could make those requests with a regular HTML form anyway (because regular HTML forms predate the idea of browsers implementing cross-origin security) so you *already* need explicit CSRF defences if you do anything with those content-types.

Comment: So the other Content-Type headers should not be allowed, too? But are for historical reasons / downward compatibility?

Comment: The three Content-Types supported by `enctype` are allowed without a preflight for historical reasons. The other ∞ are preflighted.

Comment: Follow up question: If I do not want to "change things on the server" but want to attach a payload to my cross origin request (that is then interpreted by the server): Is there an alternative type of request where I do not need to handle preflight requests? Or I am stuck to POST?

Comment: There are other HTTP verbs but all of the ones designed for changing things on the server are preflighted. Handling preflighted requests is generally not complicated, don't try to avoid them. Design your server side code so it is clear about what origins are allowed. Use existing CORS libraries for whatever server-side environment you are working in.